# Are there languages which have ways to distinguish between an adjunct noun and an adjective?

Tags: syntax, grammar, list-of-languages, adjectives, adjuncts

(Take some example). Do other languages (than English) have means distinguish between their adjunct nouns and adjectives or is it a very complex/grammatical structure that cannot possibly be represented in any language?

Comment: I don't think *faculty* in your example can be an adjective.  It's the first noun of the compound noun *faculty-office*.  As usual, the first part of the compound has more stress than the second part.

Comment: @GregLee. I agree.

Comment: Isnt that a second theory

Comment: Anyways @greglee take another example

Comment: It's better to reserve the term "adjunct" for modifiers in clause structure, and use the term 'modifier' elsewhere, for instance in NPs. In "faculty office", "faculty" is a nominal modifying "office". And unlike Greg Lee, I wouldn't call it a compound noun, since it's not morphological compound but a syntactic construction consisting  of head+ modifier.